# Show that $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1,X_2 ,\ldots$ be random variables defined by the relations
>
> $P(X_n = 0) = 1−\frac{1}{n}$, $P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2n}$ and $P(X_n = −1) = \frac{1}{2n}$ , $n\ge 1$
>
> Show that:
>
> $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad n  \rightarrow \infty$,
>
> $X_n \overset{r}{\rightarrow} 0\quad \text{ as }\quad n
>  \rightarrow \infty$ for any $r>0$

For the first one I did $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_n \ge \epsilon|)=\lim_{n \to \infty}1/2n=0$$ I used 1/2n as $X_n$ can't be as to be greater than 1.

But for the second one, I'm kind of stuck but I tried:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E(|X_n-0|^r)=\lim_{n \to \infty}E(X_n^r)=$$

Comment: Hint: $X_n$ only takes finitely many values so try using [the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) to write $\mathbb{E}[X_n^r]$ in the form $\sum a_i^r \mathbb{P}(X_n = a_i)$. (The first one is mostly correct but you should get $\frac{1}{n}$ and not $\frac{1}{2n}$ since $|-1|> \varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon$.)

Comment: why do you have $\sum a_i^r \mathbb{P}(X_n = a_i)$ instead of $\sum x^r \mathbb{P}(X_n = a_i)$ ?

Comment: $a_i$ is just a dummy variable, you can replace it with whatever you want. $\sum_{x} x^r \mathbb{P}(X_n = x)$ would be fine (but you definitely shouldn't have one occurrence of $x$ and one of $a_i$ in the sum as you do the second time round).

Comment: That is what I was missing I just forgot the dependence between these two a's or x's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert$ takes the value one with probability $1/n$ and $0$ with probability $1-1/n$ hence it is also the case for the random variable $\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert^r$. We deduce that $\mathbb E\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert^r=1/n$.